# Truffle: Creating a single ABI file if contracts are in separate .sol files?

Tags: abi, truffle-compile

I am building a project which is divided into separate .sol files, one per contract or interface. The tutorial shows a single file cryptozombies_abi.js which appears to me to be something like the json of all the separate of files found in the build folder after the compile concatenated but I am not sure. My question is, is there a way to create a single ABI from multiple sol files -- I have attempted with no success the --abi option of truffle compile which does not fail but also does not produce one large ABI -- it does produce the json still (which I am guessing are in fact ABIs for each sol file).

Comment: EDIT: Not sure that the JSON created by Truffle compilation is meant to be ABI files although I think they look like ABIs.

Answer (score 1):

Run `solc --abi` on whatever source files, and any imports will be pulled in my solc, and also compiled giving all the ABIs of every contract that was imported into that source file.

Comment: can this be done with Truffle compile? as mentioned, I tried and it does not seem to work.

Comment: I tried solcjs command line tool -- I do not see how to create a single ABI file from the ABI files produced for multiple contracts. Are they simple concatenated into a single file in a separate step?